# Getting length of words in list in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I started to write a couple functions where I could count specific words in a sentence and so on, but now I need to count the lengths of the words in a list. So I have a list where each element is a word and want to count the characters of this word.
I couldn't find any solution to do that, since Haskell doesn't use loops. Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: You can made this question better by show code you have already done. Also in haskell question it help to include type signature of your desire output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you think you need a loop when working in Haskell, you're probably looking for recursion. We'll want to recurse through the list of strings, applying the `length` function to each one. The general pattern of recursion through a list where a function is applied to each value (which you'll become very familiar with as you work through Haskell) looks roughly like this:

```
func f []     = []
func f (x:xs) = f x : func f xs
```

So we could solve the problem that way (specializing the function, rather than accepting it as an argument):

```
wordLengths :: [String] -> [Int]
wordLengths []     = []
wordLengths (x:xs) = length x : wordLengths xs
```

However, since this behavior is so common, there exists a function `map` that takes care of all of this for us. Its type signature is `(a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`, so we know to pass it a function (`length`) and a list of things (our `String`s). If we `map` the `length` function to each value in your list of strings, we'll get your desired result:

```
wordLengths :: [String] -> [Int]
wordLengths = map length
```

Example usage:

```
ghci>> wordLengths ["abc","defg"]
[3,4]
```

Comment: At first, thank you for the very good explanation! But while trying to use it, I get only the error `variable not in scope: wordLengths :: [String] -> [Int]`

Comment: I assume you're trying to enter this directly into `ghci`? The function definition I've included was intended to go in a Haskell source file. You can paste it into some file with the extension `.hs` and then load it via `ghci fileName.hs` in terminal.

Comment: I think that's what I did. I wrote a *.hs-file and added it into this. So I have to "modify" some source file of Haskell itself?
I added my entire HA.hs file.

Comment: Ah, guessed wrong. What you did should be right; it's hard to tell exactly what could be causing the problem. You've taken the second definition (with `map`, right?). If you can paste what you've included verbatim I can be more helpful :)

Comment: Yes I did. I pasted my entire script in the question. You can see it up there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129953/discussion-between-mnoronha-and-kendel-ventonda).